# Swift : #selector not recognized?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, selector

I'm new to swift and I tried to reproduce this code from a lecture of Stanford University:

```
@IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
        didSet {
            faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: #selector(FaceView.changeScale(_:))))
    }
}
```

However it gives me the error:

> 'expected expression in list of expressions'.

The error points to #selector. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you please post the code of function `changeScale(_:)` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
@IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
      didSet {
        faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: Selector(FaceView.changeScale)))
    }
}
```